# Getting expected attribute value in D3 transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For example I have a transition:

```
var sel = container.selectAll('div')
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(100,500)');
```

At some moment I need to know where some of the elements lands to, e.g.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    var value = d3.select('div#target')
        .expectedAttr('transform');
    assertEqual(value, 'translate(100,500)');
}, 500);
```

Is there built-in feature like this in D3? Otherwise I will have to write my own wrapper over `d3.transition().attr()` method for storing values passed to it.

**Edit**

I've found out that D3 creates `__transition__` field on elements, which seems to contain info regarding the transition, but I see no way to find a target attribute value there.

Comment: What do you mean by *expected* value: The value at that particular moment while the transition is still running or the target value it is transitioning to?

Comment: @altocumulus Right, I need to know the value of an attribute, that element  will have when transition ends. Maybe it is stored in some field, like `__data__` field for data bindings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At first I thought this would not be possible because the target value seemed to be inaccessibly hidden by a closure. With a little trick, though, this value can be retrieved.

You have to keep in mind that, when calling [`transition.attr()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_attr), D3 will do the following:

> For each selected element, creates an [attribute tween](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_attrTween) for the attribute with the specified name to the specified target value.

This automatically created tween can be accessed by calling [`transition.attrTween(attrName)`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_attrTween).

When this tween gets called by D3 it will return an [interpolator](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate). This in turn has access to the target value which was closed over when creating the interpolator. When reading further down the docs the real trick becomes obvious:

> The returned interpolator is then invoked for each frame of the transition, in order, being passed the eased time *t*, typically in the range [0, 1].

Knowing that the final value for t – at the end of the transition – will be *1*, you can call the previously obtained interpolator with this value which will yield the target value of the transition.

```
var targetValue = transition 
  .attrTween("x2")            // Get the tween for the desired attribute
  .call(line.node())          // Call the tween to get the interpolator
  (1);                        // Call the interpolator with 1 to get the target value
```

The following example shows this by printing the target value for an already running transition.

```js
var line = d3.select("line");
line
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .attr("x2", 100);
  
setTimeout(function() {
  var transition = d3.active(line.node())  // Get the active transition on the line
  var targetValue = transition 
    .attrTween("x2")                       // Get the tween for the desired attribute
    .call(line.node())                     // Call the tween to get the interpolator
    (1);                                   // Call the interpolator with 1 to get the target value
  console.log(targetValue);                // 100
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<svg><line x2="0" y2="100" stroke="black"></line></svg>
```

The same holds true for style transitions where you would use `transition.styleTween()` to get the tween.

Comment: Great! Is there solution for D3 v3?

Comment: @AlexanderShutov The only issue with using D3 v3 is getting the active transition on an element, i.e. calling `d3.active()` which was introduced by v4. Have a look at [*"What is the standard way to get the active (running) D3 v3 Transition for a given element?"*](/q/13844179) for a discussion. Both approaches have their drawbacks and restrictions but, depending on the rest of your code, might well be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem today and found [altocumulus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024812/9241942) very helpful. However, I discovered that (at least for the current `d3-transition@2.0.0`) if the current value is *already* at the target value, `.call`ing the `attrTween` will return `null` instead of the interpolator.

My solution wound up looking something like this:

```js
const attrTargetValue = (selection, attr) => {
  const interpolator = selection
    .attrTween(attr)
    .call(selection.node());
  return interpolator === null
    ? selection.selection().attr(attr)
    : interpolator(1);
}
```