# Flush a d3 v4 transition

Tags: d3.js, transition

Does someone know of a way to 'flush' a transition.
I have a transition defined as follows:

```
this.paths.attr('transform', null)
  .transition()
  .duration(this.duration)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.xScale(translationX) + ', 0)')
```

I am aware I can do

```
this.paths.interrupt();
```

to stop the transition, but that doesn't finish my animation. I would like to be able to 'flush' the transition which would immediately finish the animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly (and I might not) there is no out of the box solution for this without going under the hood a bit. However, I believe you could build the functionality in a relatively straightforward manner if `selection.interrupt()` is of the form you are looking for.

To do so, you'll want to create a new method for d3 selections that access the transition data (located at: `selection.node().__transition`). The transition data includes the data on the tweens, the timer, and other transition details, but the most simple solution would be to set the duration to zero which will force the transition to end and place it in its end state:

*The __transition data variable can have empty slots (of a variable number), which can cause grief in firefox (as far as I'm aware, when using forEach loops), so I've used a keys approach to get the non-empty slot that contains the transition.*

```
d3.selection.prototype.finish = function() {
    var slots = this.node().__transition;
    var keys = Object.keys(slots);
    keys.forEach(function(d,i) {
        if(slots[d]) slots[d].duration = 0;
    })  
}
```

**If working with delays**, you can also trigger the timer callback with something like: `if(slots[d]) slots[d].timer._call();`, as setting the delay to zero *does not* affect the transition.

Using this code block you call `selection.finish()` which will force the transition to its end state, click a circle to invoke the method:

```js
d3.selection.prototype.finish = function() {
  var slots = this.node().__transition;
  var keys = Object.keys(slots);
  keys.forEach(function(d,i) {
    if(slots[d]) slots[d].timer._call(); 
  }) 
}
 
var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", 500)
   .attr("height", 500);
 
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx",50)
   .attr("cy",function(d) { return d * 50 })
   .attr("r",20)
   .on("click", function() {  d3.select(this).finish() })
 
circle
   .transition()
   .delay(function(d) { return d * 500; })
   .duration(function(d) { return d* 5000; })
   .attr("cx", 460)
   .on("end", function() {
      d3.select(this).attr("fill","steelblue"); // to visualize end event
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, if you wanted to keep the method d3-ish, return the selection so you can chain additional methods on after. And for completeness, you'll want to ensure that there is a transition to finish. With these additions, the new method might look something like:

```
d3.selection.prototype.finish = function() {
  // check if there is a transition to finish:
  if (this.node().__transition) {
      // if there is transition data in any slot in the transition array, call the timer callback:
      var slots = this.node().__transition;
      var keys = Object.keys(slots);
      keys.forEach(function(d,i) {
        if(slots[d]) slots[d].timer._call(); 
   })   
  }
  // return the selection:
  return this;
}
```

Here's a [bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/d92de15ef9694f12cf5695271dd73cb8) of this more complete implementation.

---

The above is for version 4 and 5 of D3. To replicate this in version 3 is a little more difficult as timers and transitions were reworked a bit for version 4. In version three they are a bit less friendly, but the behavior can be achieved with slight modification. For completeness, [here's a block](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/ae14de2768b5d07d9fbf554ae02caf02) of a d3v3 example.

Comment: This solution works great on d3 v4.  Is it possible to do the same thing for version 3?

Comment: @Will, sure - it's a bit longer due to v3's approach to transitions and timers (as well as my comments) but still pretty concise. Behavior is the same (based on my basic testing), here's a [demonstration](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/ae14de2768b5d07d9fbf554ae02caf02).

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the example for v3.  I'm actually trying to flush the x and y axes transitions and those  __transition__ objects do not have the timer property.

Comment: If an element is transitioning with d3 it has a timer, but the enter/exit of ticks is a bit of a complication I didn't anticipate. My code for v4/v5 doesn't address axes either. While there may be some modification possible to make this work with axes, it is likely easier to use an interrupt for the children of the axis `g` (or remove them) of the axis `g` and call the axis again. Here's a [potential example](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/fffaf4738a34680b9ad7425fe13f488d). Though, this isn't super satisfying, could be worth asking this specific question for axes to get some fresh eyes on it.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the help.  Still testing it.  It works with Chrome but not PhantomJs.  Will update if/when I find something.  Would appreciate some tips if you have it.

Answer (score 4):

[Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48388508/5768908) is a great one. However, just for the sake of curiosity, I believe it can be done without extending prototypes, using `.on("interrupt"` as the listener.

Here I'm shamelessly copying Andrew code for the transitions and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024812/5768908) for getting the target attribute.

```
selection.on("click", function() {
    d3.select(this).interrupt()
})

transition.on("interrupt", function() {
    var elem = this;
    var targetValue = d3.active(this)
        .attrTween("cx")
        .call(this)(1);
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", targetValue)
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 50)
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d * 50
  })
  .attr("r", 20)
  .on("click", function() {
    d3.select(this).interrupt()
  })

circle
  .transition()
  .delay(function(d) {
    return d * 500;
  })
  .duration(function(d) {
    return d * 5000;
  })
  .attr("cx", 460)
  .on("interrupt", function() {
    var elem = this;
    var targetValue = d3.active(this)
      .attrTween("cx")
      .call(this)(1);
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", targetValue)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
```

PS: Unlike [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48388508/5768908), since I'm using `d3.active(node)` here, the click only works if the transition **had started** already.

Comment: Nice, I toyed with that approach for a bit - but despite some pretty strong swearing I couldn't quite make it work - which I'm ok with, because I like the alternative it led me to, which might be overkill, but hits the "end" event and gets all attributes being transitioned fairly simply (and I've been partial to messing with d3's innards lately).

Comment: Thanks guys! I am going to accept Gerardo's answer as I am not a big fan of extending prototypes. If I may ask a sub-question.. In your example you vary `cx` and use `attrTween('cx').call(this)(1)`, what would this become if I used an `.attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.xScale(translationX) + ', 0)')` instead?

Comment: @Gabriel I reckon you should accept Andrew's, but that's not a big deal, the accepted answer is not important here at S.O., what's important is the **upvote** (that's how the community shows that an answer is good and useful). Regarding your sub-question, it won't work because you'll **add** that value to the x position. So, for instance, if you click the circle when it is about to finish the transition, you'll add that whole x value to it. Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/n4tkq9w9/

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I update your JSFiddle to achieve what I wanted.