# How to correctly access the transform of an SVG element during d3.transition

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, transition

I'm working with d3 animations using [d3.transitions](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition) on e.g., circles.

Let's assume with have the following circle animation (d3.transition()):

```
animationTime = 500;
svg = d3.select('#svg');                      // Select the SVG by its id previously added to the DOM
circle = d3.select('#circleid')               // Select a circle by its id from the SVG
           .transform('translate(0,0)');      // Set position of that circle to origin

circle.transition().duration(animationTime)   // Start an animation with transition time of 0.5 sec
      .transform('translate(500,500)');       // Animate position of circle to new position (500, 500)

console.log(circle.attr('transform'));    // --> Output: 'translate(50,50)'
setTimeout(() => { 
   console.log(circle.attr('transform')); // --> Output: 'translate(500,500)'
}, animationTime + 50);                   // without +50 the animation is not completely finished, yet
```

My current solution is to introduce a map or element attributes to save the final position and access that SVGElement attributes instead of the transform, which makes the management of this positioning way more complicated. See here:

```
animationTime = 500;
svg = d3.select('#svg');                      
circle = d3.select('#circleid')               
           .transform('translate(0,0)');      

circle.attr('final-x', 500).attr('final-y', 500)   // Save final position as separate attribute
      .transition().duration(animationTime)   
      .transform('translate(500,500)');       

console.log(circle.attr('final-x'), circle.attr('final-y'));  // Output --> 500 500
```

Here, the values are correct, but require additional attributes **ON EACH ELEMENT**!

Therefore, I don't consider this a proper solution...

What is the standard d3 way on how to solve this issue? 
Is there a way to access the final transform state of an element without the need for additional attributes/data structures? I don't want to unnecessarily fill the DOM with garbage.

Any ideas on how to do this in a good way?

Edit: I **cannot use the .end() function** of the transition, since I already need to access the transform, already **before** the transition has finished.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014722/getting-expected-attribute-value-in-d3-transition) answer your question?

Comment: Please show how the multiple elements are managed in a code sample.

Comment: @Kaiido this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. 

It's not necessary to have multiple elements, since the problem already exists for only one circle.

I don't think it's necessary to explain the reason why I need this here? Would be to verbose I guess.

Answer (score 1):

A [`transition.end` event listener](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_on) can be added to the code, and will provide the values as at the end of the transition.

Demo in the snippet below.

```js
animationTime = 500;
circle = d3.select('#circleid')               // Select a circle by its id from the SVG
           .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)');      // Set position of that circle to origin

let t = circle.transition().duration(animationTime)   // Start an animation with transition time of 0.5 sec
      .attr('transform', 'translate(500,500)')       // Animate position of circle to new position (500, 500)

t.on('end', function() {
    console.log(circle.attr('transform'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="800" height="600" viewbox = "0 0 1000 1000">
  <circle id ="circleid" cx ="20" cy="20" r="15" fill="blue"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thx for the hint, the problem is, that I need to access the position already, before the transitions has finished, otherwise, the end function would suffice, that's true.  I forgot to mention that in the question

Comment: Ok, then please update the question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise the solutions we will propose may not match with your situation.